# Update UILabel in Different View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, ibeacon, appdelegate

I am fairly new to iOS dev. I have been trying to find an answer to this but don't have a definite solution..

I have a view called FirstView.m

And there's AppDelegate.m

A background task is running in AppDelegate.m which updates a variable called `text' depending upon the closest beacon to the phone.

When the app is in FirstView, I want to update a UILabel inside FirstView as per the variable text of AppDelegate.

I know this can be done by running a background thread in FirstView which every 1 second checks whether the variable in AppDelegate was changed or not, but this doesn't seem efficient to me at all, there is no point running two background threads for the same task.

My questions is, is there a way to update the label from AppDelegate itself ? Something on the lines of performSelectorOnMainThread ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: As in ? FirstView.m is on a Navigation Stack. So probably yes..
But I am not navigating from FirstView.m to anywhere while doing this.

Comment: As in are you using a UINavigationController... Are you using xibs or storyboards? Is there any mention of UINavigationController or UINavigationControllerDelegate in your app delegate? Does your storyboard start with a UINavigationController?

Comment: Because if you already have a reference to the "root view controller" in the app delegate, it would be easy to edit the code a little bit to access the value.

Comment: Yes I am using UINavigationController. But no mention in AppDelegate. There are other views from where I frame NavigationControllers. There is a reference to rootViewController in the navigation stack. FirstView is actually the last view in my navigation stack..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could post a notification with the text in the userInfo dictionary in the AppDelegate anytime that value changes:

```
text = [iBeacon updateText]; // just a random method name I made up
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"textChanged"
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:@{@"text":text}];
```

Then in the FirstView you can listen for that notification to update the UI (normally in `viewDidLoad` or in `viewDidAppear:`). Be sure to unregister before the view controller is dealloced somewhere in FirstView so there are no memory leaks. Example for registering and updating UI

You can register like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleTextChanged:)
                                             name:@"textChanged"
                                           object:nil];
```

Then update the UI:

```
- (void)handleTextChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Be sure to update the UI on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.label.text = notification.userInfo[@"text"];
    });
}
```

And finally, unregister for notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for! I actually never read about NSNotifications yet. I will post if I face any more questions around this!

Answer (score 0):

One more way you can try the same using `keyValue Observing`. Refer this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-178352) and [how to implement the same.](http://www.appcoda.com/understanding-key-value-observing-coding/)